# Перестала работать автоматическая перезагрузка страницы при изменении кода. VUE CLI

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Не могу понять в чем дело. После изменения расположения файлов, перестало работать автоматическое изменение на сайте. Приходится при каждом изменении самому обновлять страницу. Буду благодарен за помощь)

Во время разработки изменяю background блока div, например. Чтобы увидеть что цвет поменялся нужно перезагрузить страницу. Должно работать в автоматическом режиме, автообновление при изменении.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Убедитесь что значение переменной окружения у вас установлено в "development". Так же можете посмотреть в приложенной ссылке, вероятно там вы найдёте решение, если вышеописанное не помогло. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589853/vue-cli-3-hot-reload-suddenly-not-working-in-browsers